# DEL *.fileType not working for local directly

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-8.1

I am having some trouble deleting local files. The point is to clean up the solution directory of trash files. Here is what I have for a batch:

```
del /F /S /AH *.exe
del /F /S /AH *.ilk
del /F /S /AH *.pdb
del /F /S /AH *.sdf
```

The `*.sdf` file is in the same directory as the batch file. The rest of the files are in the `Debug` folder (which is generated by Visaul Studio). I don't want to delete all the files in the Debug folder, just those types specifically specifically. If I understand correctly, the `\S` specifies that I want the script to go into subfolders as well.

When I run the batch script, I get:

```
 Could not find [ProjectLocation]\*.exe
```

for each of the the file types

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are those files really hidden?

Comment: Good point. Does the /AH specifically go for hidden files or does it go for non-hidden and hidden at the same time?

Comment: Only for hidden files, otherwise it will give you `Could not find...`

Comment: If `del` behaves the same as `dir`, then `/a` will include all files, hidden or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that cleaning task with a single line:

```
@del /A /F /Q /S *.exe *.ilk *.pdb *.sdf >nul 2>nul
```

This command deletes all files with one of the 4 specified file extensions even if read-only or hidden in current directory and all subdirectories without any message being displayed.

PS: Care should be taken that this command is not executed on wrong directory tree.